# What is the purpose of the OAUTH_CLIENT_TOKEN table in a Spring Oauth2 JDBC implementation

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-jdbc

Do you know what is the purpose of the OAUTH_CLIENT_TOKEN table in a JDBC implementation of a Spring Oauth2 server ?

It seems that the table is never populated, however when a client obtains a token using "client credentials", its token is saved into OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN and not into OAUTH_CLIENT_TOKEN with a null username.

Here is the tables schemas very similar actually.

```
drop table if exists oauth_client_token;
create table oauth_client_token
(
    token_id          VARCHAR(255),
    token             LONGBLOB,
    authentication_id VARCHAR(255),
    user_name         VARCHAR(255),
    client_id         VARCHAR(255)
);

drop table if exists oauth_access_token;
create table `oauth_access_token`
(
    token_id          VARCHAR(255),
    token             LONGBLOB,
    authentication_id VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
    user_name         VARCHAR(255),
    client_id         VARCHAR(255),
    authentication    LONGBLOB,
    refresh_token     VARCHAR(255)
);
```

Also the configuration into the AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter

```
@Bean
public JdbcClientTokenServices clientTokenServices() {
    return new JdbcClientTokenServices(this.dataSource);
}

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new JdbcTokenStore(this.dataSource);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are referring to a table in the legacy [`spring-security-oauth` project](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security-oauth). This project is [deprecated](https://spring.io/blog/2020/05/07/end-of-life-for-spring-security-oauth). Please migrate to a supported version of Spring Security for OAuth 2.0 client support. You can follow the official migration guide [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide).

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana Thanks I didn't know it was deprecated... I found another topic about a new authorisation server [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59273338/what-is-the-replacement-for-the-deprecated-authorizationserver-in-spring-securit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That table doesn't seem to be used anymore. The legacy Spring oauth2 authorization server will reach end of live in may 22.