# why jwt token is showing invalid signature in spring security 6 by pasting it in jwt.io

Tags: spring-security, jwt, nimbus-jose-jwt

I'm using Spring Security 6 using Nimbus token.
Here is my security configuration ..

```
@Bean
public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
    return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey( jwtConfigProperties.getPublicKey()).build();
} 

@Bean 
public JwtEncoder jwtEncoder(){ 
    JWK jwk = new RSAKey.Builder( jwtConfigProperties.getPublicKey()).privateKey(jwtConfigProperties.getPrivateKey()).build(); 
    JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwks = new ImmutableJWKSet<>(new JWKSet(jwk));
    return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwks);
}
```

Here's my jwt configuration properties for RSA public and private key..

```
public class RsaKeyProperties {

    private RSAPrivateKey privateKey;
    
    private RSAPublicKey publicKey;
    
    @Autowired
    KeyGeneratorUtility keygen;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        KeyPair keyPair = keygen.generateKey();
        
        this.privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        System.out.println("rsa private key : "+privateKey);
        this.publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        System.out.println("rsa public key : "+publicKey);
    }
}
```

And here's to generate RSA public and private key programmatically.

```
public class KeyGeneratorUtility {
    
    public KeyPair generateKey() {
        
        KeyPair keyPair;

        try{
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        } catch(Exception e){
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }

        return keyPair;
    }
}
```

And here is to generate token programmatically.

```
public String generateToken(ProductUser produser) {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        String scope = produser.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
        
        JwtClaimsSet claims = JwtClaimsSet.builder()
                .issuer("self")
                .issuedAt(now)
                .expiresAt(now.plus(1, ChronoUnit.HOURS))
                .subject(produser.getUsername())
                .claim("scope", scope)
                .build();
        
        return this.encoder.encode(JwtEncoderParameters.from(claims)).getTokenValue();
    }
```

This is an auto-generated token after hitting API from postman with status 200 OK

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzZWxmIiwic3ViIjoic2F5YW50YW51c2VyIiwiZXhwIjoxNjkyNzY1MTU5LCJpYXQiOjE2OTI3NjE1NTksInNjb3BlIjoidXNlcjpjcmVhdGUgdXNlcjpkZWxldGUgdXNlcjp1cGRhdGUgdXNlcjpyZWFkIFJPTEVfVVNFUiJ9.LtLP0YcniqgKbhqMkTOWtBMqGLKP1nk5xKWZhELmsISCFTPmMbCVCAPikJqz9psW3QjoMWgbOoia3_saohrbPI1EfTIYb_P0K5bh3eD2StIK0B4ywf39-ENvzE9Zt9GuRTWHQ7tk1cBJv9YhqZxDzmFbZdPDBB1ZWYXGLxBhKec8vVlidGA0UqPKNiZhSFoop3mjmzu2N4kah7WZ__q20ccFeS52icKXyw8kpFbxiasouWRLPjy75nwgcYhXASKfs5TSYPyzppCTE1cqQ3CzVOv21xpzK6QjD9hnTz8aqrsz8mFTFxd0VRqenwLx1s9SiHldfG0DK_umd9w_83muoQ
```

But after pasting this token with JWT.io it is showing invalid signature
[image]

An idea what am I doing wrong?
Is my approach incorrect?
Please help me out.

Comment: why are you even generating a token in your application, and not letting a proper authorization server/issuer generate tokens for you

Comment: I just want to create a token programmatically without using openssl tool with issuer by myself.

Comment: You did not paste the public key into the public key field on jwt.io (righ column under VERIFY SIGNATURE). Without knowing the public key, the signature can't be verified.

Comment: I'll try that. thnx for help.

Comment: Just so you know, creating tokens and giving them out to browsers is very dangerous.

Comment: AFAIK @Toerktumlare, Authorization Server also generates self-signed token and send it to its client.

Comment: no they dont, the implicit oauth2 flow is deprecated and is not used anymore, and still OWASPs best practices are still and has always been to not supply browsers with tokens directly, Open ID connect supplyes tokens in cookies with the httpOnly flag set. Just because a lot of people do give out JWTs to browsers does not mean that they are doing something secure. Why do you think there are a lot of insecure applications out there? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JdGOb7AxUo0

Comment: hmm.. thanx for your info. I'll check that out. And also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59273338/what-is-the-replacement-for-the-deprecated-authorizationserver-in-spring-securit

Comment: May be it is still there .. https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/overview.html#feature-list